# Network Unclaimed - Ubuntu 20.04 on freshly installed machine

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu on my brand new lenovo laptop:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and now, I can not use my wifi. After I checked `sudo lshw -C network`, I found that the network is UNCLAIMED

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a120ffff
```

Then I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` which gave me:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, rtl8821ce
```

I came across similar problem and the solution was to install the correct firmware, however that was for ubuntu 16.04 and I was also not sure whether I have the same problem.

Here is my kernel version, running `uname -a` gave me:

```
Linux philgun-Lenovo-V15-IWL 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What should I do?

Thank you
P

Answer (score 1):

Please start by blacklisting the ineffective driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtw88_8821ce"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtw88_8821ce
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

**EDIT**: To install the latest rtl8821ce driver, get a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Reboot.

Comment: Hi Chili555, thanks for answering my question. Apologies for taking a long time to respond,, I was travelling abroad. I 

tried your suggestion and it is still showing Unclaimed
```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

I have no idea what I should do now.

Comment: Your original question suggested that you had the preferred driver rtl8821ce installed. Did you try it? If you have the files on your system, try to reinstall the rtl8821ce driver. If you do not, I will edit my answer to give a solution.

Comment: Hi Chilli, I could not find rtl8821ce driver in my system. How do i install it? 

Sorry for the late reply, I been travelling

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.